# django allauth redirect issue debug

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I am facing some problem while working with django-allauth. I am using google authentication with the help of django-allauth. I have set the redirect url in the google api console as directed in the official documentation.Also, I have set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL as stated in the documentation.

**Authorized redirect url in google api console:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

**Settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "user_dashboard"
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {
        'access_type': 'online',
        'hd': 'xxx.yyy'
        }
    }
}
```

**urls.py**

```
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
url(r"accounts/profile/logout", views.my_logout, name="logout"),
url(r'^accounts/',include("allauth.urls")),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^admin/inventory_management_app/device/router_specifications/', views.pdf_download, name = "pdfdownload"),
url(r'^admin/inventory_management_app/repair/repair_invoice/', views.repair_pdf_download, name = "pdfdownload"),
url(r'accounts/profile/home',views.my_dashboard,name='user_dashboard'),
url(r'accounts/profile/user_dashboard', views.my_dashboard, name = "user_dashboard"),
```

I get a social network authentication failure. I overrode the authentication_error.html to find the cause but, still did not get any workable response. 
requesting your help at the earliest.

Comment: show us the exact error you're getting. What is "social network authentication failure"?